# Display files located in a folder and display them in a drop down for selection using javascript html for a metro app

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I'm trying to create a drop down select that will display files in a folder to select from.  I'm developing this in Windows 8 using javascript and html for a metro app.

Comment: Whats the question? Accessing the list of files? a drop down?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I want to list files in a directory and display them in a dropdown using javascript and html.   Windows 8 app